# Swift nested class as mocks

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I would like to use nested classes in Swift for mocking purposes. Imagine `bar()` method of following `Foo` class is under the test:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    func baz() -> String {
        return "baz"
    }

    func bar() -> String {
        return self.baz().stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("z", withString: "r")
    }
}
```

I want to mock `baz()` method and verify that `bar()` depends on it with following test:

```
class FooTests: XCTestCase {
    func testBar() {
        class FooMock: Foo {
            override func baz() -> String {
                return "zzz"
            }
        }

        let mock = FooMock()
        let result = mock.bar()

        XCTAssertEqual("rrr", result)
    }
}
```

I have `Foo` class added to both application and test targets to bypass access modifiers issue with test target.

The application fails to compile with below error:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
%4* (%0*, i8*)* @_TToFCFC13TestTestTests8FooTests7testBarFS0_FT_T_L_7FooMock3bazfS1_FT_SS
invalid linkage type for function declaration
%4* (%0*, i8*)* @_TToFCFC13TestTestTests8FooTests7testBarFS0_FT_T_L_7FooMock3bazfS1_FT_SS
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
```

After moving `FooMock` to separate source file it compiles and works just fine.

When using nested class to mock any methods from iOS standard frameworks it works just fine:

```
func testMockDefaults() {
    class NSUserDefaultsMock: NSUserDefaults {
        override func objectForKey(defaultName: String) -> AnyObject? {
            return "Super secret!"
        }
    }

    let defaults = NSUserDefaultsMock(suiteName: "SuiteName")!
    defaults.setObject("Test", forKey: "Test")
    let result = defaults.objectForKey("Test") as String

    XCTAssertEqual("Super secret!", result)
}
```

Could you please explain me what am I missing and what is the reason behind this?